On generating tight instances of Max Cover / NP-hard Problems
In the Max Cover NP-hard problem, a greedy algorithm provides a theoretical lower bound of $(1-1/e) \cdot OPT$, where OPT represents the optimal solution (reference). I am interested in randomly generating a set of "tight" problem instances on which the greedy approach performs exactly or approximately equal to $(1-1/e) \cdot OPT$.
To do this, I attempted to study the proof for the approximation lower bound guarantee and observed the following 2 rules.

Rule 1: If $G_{i}$ represents the greedy solution at iteration i, OPT is the optimal solution, and k is the number of sets to be selected, then $G_{i+1}$ must take up $1/k \cdot (OPT - G_i)$
Rule 2: The remaining sets should divide the space $(OPT - G_{i+1})$ into k equal parts.

I still don't fully understand what algorithm I can use to create instances following the above rules.  Can anyone guide me, please?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. In case it helps, one instance of a tight Max Cover instance (not necessarily following the above-mentioned rules) is as below:
N = 12
K = 2
S = {A, B, C}
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
B = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
C = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
Here, Greedy chooses {B, A} or {B, C} as the solution as B has the most uncovered elements in the first iteration. Whereas OPT = {A, C}, achieving maximum possible coverage. In short, set B distracts the greedy into making a sub-optimal greedy choice.
